# Why doesn't my funciton run when I put it in a class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

New to js-classes so this might be a rookie mistake, but here goes:

I'm trying to run a throttled event when scrolling

```
scrollEvent = () =>{
   console.log('test')
}
```

When I have a throttle like this:

```
throttle = (fn, wait) => {
    var time = Date.now();
    return function() {
        if ((time + wait - Date.now()) < 0 && !transitioning) {
            fn();
            time = Date.now();
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(scrollEvent, 50));
```

It works fine, but when I try to move the throttle to a class:

```
Throttle = class{
        constructor(){
            this.on = true; 
        }
        run(fn, wait) {
            var time = Date.now();
            return function() {
                if ((time + wait - Date.now()) < 0 && this.on) {
                    fn();
                    time = Date.now();
                }
            }
        },
scroll = new Throttle();
window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll.run(scrollEvent, 50));
```

The event won't trigger on scroll.

Comment: Why would you make that a class? There's no good reason for having an instance here.

Comment: `this` in the function returned by `scroll.run()` is chosen by the event triggerer, it does refer to `window` not to the instance and `this.on` is always `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi Right now, the variable transitioning is a global varaible, I'd like to keep it in a scope somehow. Am very open to other suggestions.

Comment: You also need to close the block. It's missing a `}`. The arrow function is also incorrect. Either add a `=` after `run` or remove the `=>`

Comment: A duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: @estus, same solution, but different quesitons imo :) Thanks though!

Comment: @Himmators Ah, I see, so you'd then use `scroll.on = false/true` in your code? I guess a class would be ok for that. Just use arrow function syntax for the returned function and it should work.

Comment: The question is same, as long as the problem behind it is understood correctly. `run` returns a callback. It shoud be `return () => {...`

Comment: Thx, I understand the problem now, with the scope of "this", not sure what's the best way to get around it though...   `window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll.run(()=>{scrollEvent()}, 50));`